# Canvas Animation not working smoothly

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to update a barrage of bullets each frame in JavaScript, but it seems it's not working properly. Here's the code I put on JSFiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/Reverseblade/co2mpLnv/5/

```js
var ctx;
    var hero;
    var enemy;
    var beams = [];
    var beam_hitting = false;
    var continuous_hit = false;
    var count = 0;
    var canvas_w = 500, canvas_y= 700;
    var keycode = NaN;
    var laser_degree = 200;

    function init(){
      createCanvas();
      createMainHero();
      createEnemy();
      draw();
      mainRoutine();
    }

    function mainRoutine(){
      count++;
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas_w, canvas_y);
      // laserTest();

      hero.move(keycode);
      enemyUpdate();
      // hero.setBullets();
      // hero.moveBullets();
      draw();

      window.setTimeout(mainRoutine, 7);
    }

    function createCanvas(){
      var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      canvas.id = "canvas";
      canvas.width = canvas_w;
      canvas.height = canvas_y;
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    }

    function createMainHero(){
      hero = new Hero();
    }

    function createEnemy(){
      enemy = new Enemy;
    }


    function Hero(){
      this.w = this.h = 25,
      this.x = canvas_w/2 - this.w/2,
      this.y = canvas_y - this.h,
      this.dx = this.dy = 2.5;
      this.bullets = [];
      this.move = function(key){
        switch(key){
          case 37: if (hero.x > 0) {hero.x -= this.dx;} break;
          case 38: if (hero.y > 0) {hero.y -= this.dy;} break;
          case 39: if (hero.x < canvas_w - hero.w) {hero.x += this.dx;} break;
          case 40: if (hero.y < canvas_y - hero.h) {hero.y += this.dy;} break;
        }
      };
      this.setBullets = function(){
        if (count % 20 === 0) {
          var w = h = 8;
          var dx = dy = 5;
          var x = hero.x + hero.w/2 - w/2;
          var y = hero.y;
          hero.bullets.push({x: x, y: y, w: w, h: h, dx: dx, dy: dy, moving:true});
        }
      };
      this.moveBullets = function(){
      for (var i = 0; i < this.bullets.length; i++) {
        if (this.bullets[i].y < 0) {
          this.bullets[i].moving = false;
          continue;
        }
        if (this.bullets[i].moving === false) {
          continue;
        }
        this.bullets[i].y -= this.bullets[i].dy;
        if (this.bullets[i].y < -100) {this.bullets.splice(i, 1)}
      }
    }

    }

    function Enemy(){
      this.w = this.h = 25;
      this.x = canvas_w/2 - this.w/2;
      this.y = 50;
      this.bullets = [];
      this.moving = false;
      this.move_to = 0;
      this.bullets_count = 0;
      this.bullets_angle = 0;
      this.current_skill = 1;
      this.barrage_count = 0;
      this.skill = function(){
        enemySkill();
      };
    }


    function enemyUpdate(){

      function move(){

        function changeDirection(){
          var options = ["left", "right", "up", "down"];
          var id;
          if (enemy.x <= 50) {id = options.indexOf("left"); options.splice(id, 1);}
          if (enemy.x >= 450) {id = options.indexOf("right");options.splice(id, 1);}
          if (enemy.y <= 50) {id = options.indexOf("up");options.splice(id, 1);}
          if (enemy.y >= 200) {id = options.indexOf("down");options.splice(id, 1);}

          var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length);
          enemy.moving = options[rand];

          switch(enemy.moving){
            case "left": enemy.move_to = enemy.x - 150 ; break;
            case "right": enemy.move_to = enemy.x + 150 ; break;
            case "up": enemy.move_to = enemy.y - 150 ; break;
            case "down": enemy.move_to = enemy.y + 150 ; break;
          }
        } /* end changeDirection() */

        if (count % 800 === 0) {changeDirection(); console.log("changing");}


        switch(enemy.moving){
          case "left": if (enemy.x > 50 && enemy.x > enemy.move_to) {enemy.x -= 0.5;} break;
          case "right": if (enemy.x < 450 && enemy.x < enemy.move_to) {enemy.x += 0.5;} break;
          case "up": if (enemy.y > 50 && enemy.y > enemy.move_to) {enemy.y -= 0.5; } break;
          case "down": if (enemy.y < 200 && enemy.y < enemy.move_to) {enemy.y += 0.5; } break;
        }

      } /* end move()*/

      move();
      enemy.skill();
    } /* end enemyUpdate() */

    function enemySkill(){
      // console.log("enemy skill");
      function setBullets(){
        var prev_status = enemy.bullets_count === 0 ? 500 : enemy.bullets[enemy.bullets.length - 1]["radius"];
        if (prev_status >25) {
           // console.log("bullets set");
          var center_x = enemy.x + enemy.w/2;
          var center_y = enemy.y + enemy.h/2;
          var radius = 20;
          var ceil = enemy.bullets.length === 0 ? 0 : enemy.bullets.length -1;
          for (var angle = enemy.bullets_angle, i= ceil; angle < enemy.bullets_angle + 360; angle += 40, i++ ) {
            // console.log("i: " + i);
            var radian = angle * Math.PI / 180;
            var set_x = center_x + radius * Math.cos(radian);
            var set_y = center_y + radius * Math.sin(radian);
            // console.log("angle: " + /angle + "set_x: " + set_x + "set_y: " + set_y);
            enemy.bullets.push({"x": set_x, "y": set_y, "moving": true, "radius": radius, "center_x": center_x, "center_y": center_y, "w": 25, "h": 25, "radian": radian});
            if (enemy.bullets_count === 0) {enemy.bullets_count++;}
            // console.log(enemy.bullets[0][i]["x"]);
         }
         enemy.bullets_angle += 10;
         enemy.barrage_count ++;
         if (enemy.barrage_count % 100 === 0) {
           enemy.current_skill = 0;
         }
        }

      } /* end setBullets */


      function moveBullets(){
        if (count % 4 ===0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < enemy.bullets.length; i++) {
            if (enemy.bullets[i]["moving"] === true) {
              var radian = enemy.bullets[i]["radian"];
              var center_x = enemy.bullets[i]["center_x"];
              var center_y = enemy.bullets[i]["center_y"];
              enemy.bullets[i]["radius"] += 5;
              var radius = enemy.bullets[i]["radius"];
              var set_x = center_x + radius * Math.cos(radian);
              var set_y = center_y + radius * Math.sin(radian);
              // console.log(set_y);
              enemy.bullets[i]["x"] = set_x;
              enemy.bullets[i]["y"] = set_y;
              if (enemy.bullets[i]["x"] < -100 || enemy.bullets[i]["x"] > canvas_w + 100 || enemy.bullets[i]["y"] < -100 || enemy.bullets[i]["y"] > canvas_y + 100 ) {
                // enemy.bullets[i]["moving"] = false;
                enemy.bullets.splice(i, 1);
              }

              }
            }
          }
        }

      if (enemy.current_skill === 1) {
        setBullets();
      }
      moveBullets();
    }

    


    function draw(){
      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      //hero
      //ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
      //ctx.fillRect(hero.x, hero.y ,hero.w, hero.h);

      //enemy
      //ctx.fillStyle = "red";
      //ctx.fillRect(enemy.x, enemy.y ,enemy.w, enemy.h);

      //heroの弾
      ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
      for (var i = 0; i < hero.bullets.length; i++) {
        if (hero.bullets[i].moving === false) {
          continue;
        }
        ctx.fillRect(hero.bullets[i].x, hero.bullets[i].y ,hero.bullets[i].w, hero.bullets[i].h);
      }

      //敵の弾
      ctx.fillStyle = "red";
      for (var i = 0; i < enemy.bullets.length; i++) {
         ctx.fillStyle = "green";

        if (enemy.bullets[i]["moving"] === false) {
          continue;
        }

          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(enemy.bullets[i]["x"], enemy.bullets[i]["y"], 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
          ctx.closePath();
          ctx.fill();

      }
    }





    window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
      switch(e.keyCode){
        case 37: keycode = 37; break;
        case 38: keycode = 38; break;
        case 39: keycode = 39; break;
        case 40: keycode = 40; break;
      }
    }, false);

    window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
      switch(e.keyCode){
        case 37: keycode = NaN; break;
        case 38: keycode = NaN; break;
        case 39: keycode = NaN; break;
        case 40: keycode = NaN; break;
      }
    }, false);


    init();
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#canvas{
  background:url("../img/seamles_space.jpg");
  animation: mainBack 5s linear infinite;
  animation-play-state:paused;
  background: black;
  display: block;
  position:relative;
  margin:50px auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
var ctx;
var hero;
var enemy;
var beams = [];
var beam_hitting = false;
var continuous_hit = false;
var count = 0;
var canvas_w = 500, canvas_y= 700;
var keycode = NaN;
var laser_degree = 200;

function init(){
  createCanvas();
  createMainHero();
  createEnemy();
  draw();
  mainRoutine();
}

function mainRoutine(){
  count++;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas_w, canvas_y);
  // laserTest();

  hero.move(keycode);
  enemyUpdate();
  // hero.setBullets();
  // hero.moveBullets();
  draw();

  window.setTimeout(mainRoutine, 7);
}

function createCanvas(){
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.id = "canvas";
  canvas.width = canvas_w;
  canvas.height = canvas_y;
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
}

function createMainHero(){
  hero = new Hero();
}

function createEnemy(){
  enemy = new Enemy;
}


function Hero(){
  this.w = this.h = 25,
  this.x = canvas_w/2 - this.w/2,
  this.y = canvas_y - this.h,
  this.dx = this.dy = 2.5;
  this.bullets = [];
  this.move = function(key){
    switch(key){
      case 37: if (hero.x > 0) {hero.x -= this.dx;} break;
      case 38: if (hero.y > 0) {hero.y -= this.dy;} break;
      case 39: if (hero.x < canvas_w - hero.w) {hero.x += this.dx;} break;
      case 40: if (hero.y < canvas_y - hero.h) {hero.y += this.dy;} break;
    }
  };
  this.setBullets = function(){
    if (count % 20 === 0) {
      var w = h = 8;
      var dx = dy = 5;
      var x = hero.x + hero.w/2 - w/2;
      var y = hero.y;
      hero.bullets.push({x: x, y: y, w: w, h: h, dx: dx, dy: dy, moving:true});
    }
  };
  this.moveBullets = function(){
  for (var i = 0; i < this.bullets.length; i++) {
    if (this.bullets[i].y < 0) {
      this.bullets[i].moving = false;
      continue;
    }
    if (this.bullets[i].moving === false) {
      continue;
    }
    this.bullets[i].y -= this.bullets[i].dy;
    if (this.bullets[i].y < -100) {this.bullets.splice(i, 1)}
  }
}

}

function Enemy(){
  this.w = this.h = 25;
  this.x = canvas_w/2 - this.w/2;
  this.y = 50;
  this.bullets = [];
  this.moving = false;
  this.move_to = 0;
  this.bullets_count = 0;
  this.bullets_angle = 0;
  this.current_skill = 1;
  this.barrage_count = 0;
  this.skill = function(){
    enemySkill();
  };
}


function enemyUpdate(){

  function move(){

    function changeDirection(){
      var options = ["left", "right", "up", "down"];
      var id;
      if (enemy.x <= 50) {id = options.indexOf("left"); options.splice(id, 1);}
      if (enemy.x >= 450) {id = options.indexOf("right");options.splice(id, 1);}
      if (enemy.y <= 50) {id = options.indexOf("up");options.splice(id, 1);}
      if (enemy.y >= 200) {id = options.indexOf("down");options.splice(id, 1);}

      var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length);
      enemy.moving = options[rand];

      switch(enemy.moving){
        case "left": enemy.move_to = enemy.x - 150 ; break;
        case "right": enemy.move_to = enemy.x + 150 ; break;
        case "up": enemy.move_to = enemy.y - 150 ; break;
        case "down": enemy.move_to = enemy.y + 150 ; break;
      }
    } /* end changeDirection() */

    if (count % 800 === 0) {changeDirection(); console.log("changing");}


    switch(enemy.moving){
      case "left": if (enemy.x > 50 && enemy.x > enemy.move_to) {enemy.x -= 0.5;} break;
      case "right": if (enemy.x < 450 && enemy.x < enemy.move_to) {enemy.x += 0.5;} break;
      case "up": if (enemy.y > 50 && enemy.y > enemy.move_to) {enemy.y -= 0.5; } break;
      case "down": if (enemy.y < 200 && enemy.y < enemy.move_to) {enemy.y += 0.5; } break;
    }

  } /* end move()*/

  move();
  enemy.skill();
} /* end enemyUpdate() */

function enemySkill(){
  // console.log("enemy skill");
  function setBullets(){
    var prev_status = enemy.bullets_count === 0 ? 500 : enemy.bullets[enemy.bullets.length - 1]["radius"];
    if (prev_status >25) {
       // console.log("bullets set");
      var center_x = enemy.x + enemy.w/2;
      var center_y = enemy.y + enemy.h/2;
      var radius = 20;
      var ceil = enemy.bullets.length === 0 ? 0 : enemy.bullets.length -1;
      for (var angle = enemy.bullets_angle, i= ceil; angle < enemy.bullets_angle + 360; angle += 40, i++ ) {
        // console.log("i: " + i);
        var radian = angle * Math.PI / 180;
        var set_x = center_x + radius * Math.cos(radian);
        var set_y = center_y + radius * Math.sin(radian);
        // console.log("angle: " + /angle + "set_x: " + set_x + "set_y: " + set_y);
        enemy.bullets.push({"x": set_x, "y": set_y, "moving": true, "radius": radius, "center_x": center_x, "center_y": center_y, "w": 25, "h": 25, "radian": radian});
        if (enemy.bullets_count === 0) {enemy.bullets_count++;}
        // console.log(enemy.bullets[0][i]["x"]);
     }
     enemy.bullets_angle += 10;
     enemy.barrage_count ++;
     if (enemy.barrage_count % 100 === 0) {
       enemy.current_skill = 0;
     }
    }

  } /* end setBullets */


  function moveBullets(){
    if (count % 4 ===0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < enemy.bullets.length; i++) {
        if (enemy.bullets[i]["moving"] === true) {
          var radian = enemy.bullets[i]["radian"];
          var center_x = enemy.bullets[i]["center_x"];
          var center_y = enemy.bullets[i]["center_y"];
          enemy.bullets[i]["radius"] += 5;
          var radius = enemy.bullets[i]["radius"];
          var set_x = center_x + radius * Math.cos(radian);
          var set_y = center_y + radius * Math.sin(radian);
          // console.log(set_y);
          enemy.bullets[i]["x"] = set_x;
          enemy.bullets[i]["y"] = set_y;
          if (enemy.bullets[i]["x"] < -100 || enemy.bullets[i]["x"] > canvas_w + 100 || enemy.bullets[i]["y"] < -100 || enemy.bullets[i]["y"] > canvas_y + 100 ) {
            // enemy.bullets[i]["moving"] = false;
            enemy.bullets.splice(i, 1);
          }

          }
        }
      }
    }

  if (enemy.current_skill === 1) {
    setBullets();
  }
  moveBullets();
}




function draw(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  //hero
  //ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  //ctx.fillRect(hero.x, hero.y ,hero.w, hero.h);

  //enemy
  //ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  //ctx.fillRect(enemy.x, enemy.y ,enemy.w, enemy.h);

  //heroの弾
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  for (var i = 0; i < hero.bullets.length; i++) {
    if (hero.bullets[i].moving === false) {
      continue;
    }
    ctx.fillRect(hero.bullets[i].x, hero.bullets[i].y ,hero.bullets[i].w, hero.bullets[i].h);
  }

  //敵の弾
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  for (var i = 0; i < enemy.bullets.length; i++) {
     ctx.fillStyle = "green";

    if (enemy.bullets[i]["moving"] === false) {
      continue;
    }

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(enemy.bullets[i]["x"], enemy.bullets[i]["y"], 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fill();

  }
}





window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
  switch(e.keyCode){
    case 37: keycode = 37; break;
    case 38: keycode = 38; break;
    case 39: keycode = 39; break;
    case 40: keycode = 40; break;
  }
}, false);

window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
  switch(e.keyCode){
    case 37: keycode = NaN; break;
    case 38: keycode = NaN; break;
    case 39: keycode = NaN; break;
    case 40: keycode = NaN; break;
  }
}, false);


init();
```

There's no problem at the beginning, but then some of the bullets would start acting weirdly as if after some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is that an item is removed while in a for-loop, causing one bullet to be skipped, more precisely, this line:

```
enemy.bullets.splice(i, 1);
```

I would suggest a different approach - build a new array only consisting of the active bullets (`moving===true`), then after the loop replace the array with the new.

For example:

```
  function moveBullets(){
    if (count % 4 ===0) {

      // will hold active bullets in current pass
      var newBullets = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < enemy.bullets.length; i++) {
          // cut code for clarity

          if (!(enemy.bullets[i].x < -100 || enemy.bullets[i].x > canvas_w + 100 || 
                enemy.bullets[i].y < -100 || enemy.bullets[i].y > canvas_y + 100 )) {
            newBullets.push(enemy.bullets[i]);
          }
      }

      // replace array with only active bullets
      enemy.bullets = newBullets;
    }
 }
```

The new array will simply hold references to existing active bullets.

[Modified Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/co2mpLnv/9/)

Comment: how about you do splice, but then remember to decrement `i`?

Comment: @towc that is possible too. I landed on the above as push is slightly faster than doing splice (but not that important here as there are many other aspects of this code that needs optimizations). Splicing will also change the length property which I believe will affect any internal optimizations of it (as cached value).

Comment: not in this case. You're pushing for every item, and creating a new array with a new reference each time, overworking the GC quite a bit. This is considerably slower than splicing a few times, even considered the optimizations that go with the constant value for the termination condition. I'll edit if that's okay

Comment: actually, it would make more sense for it to be a separate answer, unless you want to edit yours yourself. If I'd do it, it would be completely different than what you're suggesting here

Comment: @towc maybe I am misunderstanding what you're saying, but this [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/splice-vs-push-to-remove-items) gives indication to what I state above ie. that the push approach is faster. But maybe I overlooked something?

Comment: this is closer to the current scenario: https://jsperf.com/splice-vs-push-in-array-frames/1

removal frequency is much lower than half, and you're repeating this multiple times. This doesn't even take in garbage collection because of the way tests are done

Comment: @towc push is still faster (on my PC at least). But anyways, we are getting out on a tangent here in regards to OPs problem. I would agree with the other answer that pooling/reuse is a better solution overall, but the *actual* problem in OPs existing code is that an item is skipped when another is removed from the array.

Comment: yeah sure, this is a valid solution :)
It's weird, push is 50% slower for me in the last example

Answer (score 1):

### Particles and object pools.

Creating a new array is not a good strategy when dealing with particle systems. Which is what bullets are in effect.

Each bullet deleted, will need to be cleaned up by GC (Garbage Collection), each bullet added needs to be created and requires memory allocation. These overhead can have a negative effect on a game. GC can cause an animation to hang at random times.

For consistent, smooth animation you should aim for zero allocation and deletion (which is possible as asm.js and web Assembly do not allocate or delete inside a running modula).

#### Object pool

In vanilla JS it is possible but the code is too complex for this answer. The next best solution is to use a object pool.

As bullets are first created as normal, but when a bullet is no longer needed rather than dereference it you move it to another array (called the pool), next time a bullet is needed you first check if any are available on the pool and use that rather than create a new object.

This ensures that GC only has to clean up the changing array sizes and not the data used by each bullet.

```
var bullets = [];
var bulletPool = [];

function createBullet(x,y,dir,whatNot){
    var newBullet;
    if(bulletPool.length > 0){
        newBullet = bulletPool.pop();  // reuse old bullet memory
        newBullet.x = x;  
        newBullet.y = y;  
        newBullet.dir = dir;  
        newBullet.whatNot = whatNot;  
        newBullet.active = true;
    }else{
        newBullet = {x,y,dir,whatNot,active:true};  // create only if needed

    }
    return newBullet;
}
function fire(){
    bullets.push(createBullet(10,10,0,0)); /// add a bullet
}
```

In your code when a bullet is no longer needed just set the active flag to false. At the end of the game loop remove all the inactive bullets.

When you delete a bullet just move it from the bullet array to the pool

```
function cleanBulletsArray(){
     for(var i = 0; i < bullets.length; i ++){
         if(!bullets[i].active){
              bulletPool.push(bullets.splice(i--,1)[0]);
         }
     }
}
```

#### Precipitation array

So called because the active items fall to the bottom of the array

An even better method is to use just one array. When a bullet is not active it stays in the array, but as you iterate the array you swap active bullets for inactive, with active bullets moving down and inactive up. There is at most one swap per iteration. You also keep a count of the number of active bullets. When you need a new bullet you just reset the properties of the bullet at index count + 1 and then increase count by one.

This method (if you pre allocate all the bullets at the start of the game) has zero GC and Memory overhead and is significantly quicker than the creation, destruction, and array replacement methods.